# PowerShell: Script failing because AD objects have not replicated soon enough

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that creates two groups, a hand full of folders, and sets permissions on those folders. In my testing environment all of these processes work without issue but in my production environment I run into a problem. Setting the permissions on the folders fail since the groups I created have not replicated through all 8 of my domain controllers. Can have PowerShell work with only one of the DC's so I don't have to wait for the replication? Should I put the script to sleep for X seconds? Or is there some way to see if the groups are on all the DC's or at least on the one I am working?

This is how I am making the groups:

```
New-ADGroup -Name $Admin_GRP -path "OU=Users,OU=Sandbox,DC=test,DC=local" -GroupScope Global
New-ADGroup -Name $User_GRP -path "OU=Users,OU=Sandbox,DC=test,DC=local" -GroupScope Global
```

This is how I am setting the permissions on one of the folders:

```
#Set permissions on root directory
$ACL = Get-Acl $PathToFolder
#For Admin
$Permission = $Admin_GRP,"Write,ReadAndExecute,Synchronize,DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles","Allow"
$Access_Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $Permission
$ACL.AddAccessRule($Access_Rule)
$ACL | Set-Acl $PathToFolder
#For Users
$Permission = $User_GRP,"ReadAndExecute,Synchronize","Allow"
$Access_Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $Permission
$ACL.AddAccessRule($Access_Rule)
$ACL | Set-Acl $PathToFolder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the permission on the SID of the new group instead of it's name/samaccountname.

Comment: I am getting the same error 
"Exception calling "Translate" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At :line:36 char:83
+ $Admin_SID = (new-object system.security.principal.NtAccount($Admin_GRP)).translate <<<< ([system.security.principal.securityidentifier]).value"

Comment: Yes you are running into the same problem here, you should read the SID from the created object (I assume $Admin_GRP is the accountname and not an object)

Answer (score 1):

In the past, when writing shell scripts, I've called NLTEST.EXE to point the current PC/server at a specific DC (I normally choose the PDC emulator).  I can't remember which switch I used.  Not sure if this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a while loop to check for the group replication.

```
#Wait for group replication
while ($Admin_GRP_CHK -ne 'group')
{$Admin_GRP_CHK = (Get-ADGroup $Admin_GRP).ObjectClass
trap {'Admin group not replicated yet. Waiting 10 seconds.' -f $_.Exception.Message;    continue}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
Write-Host 'Admin group exists'
```

Comment: In a larger AD environment it may take a while for the replication so I think this is a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. It turns out, our filesystem only updated it's own cache of SIDs every 20 - 30 seconds. So if I created a new SID and tried to apply it to a folder straight away, our filesystem would say the SID was unknown. I modified a setting on our filesystem to allow it to accept 'unknown' SIDs (even though they were known to AD and it just hadn't updated). More info here:

[Issues With New-ADGroup, Set-ACL and Network Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712311/issues-with-new-adgroup-set-acl-and-network-folders)

Sleeping the script is definitely not an option when you have 7.5 million files and folders!