# Setting Permissions for a user who hasn't propagated yet

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I'm trying to set permissions for a folder in Powershell. My problem is that I am setting these permissions on an active directory account that is recently created on one of our head Domain Controllers. Since the account is brand new, it hasn't propagated down to any of our local DCs  yet. This is causing a problem for me, since I am trying to set the folder to allow that user to have modify access and Powershell is tossing a "Some or all identity references could not be translated." error when I try to call SetAccessRule on the folder's ACL. Example code shown below.

```
#I'm actually setting more details than this for the account, but I abbreviated
#the command to make it a little more readable
New-ADUser -Name "Testy Testerson" -Server Master-DC.Domain.ca

$DirectoryLocation = '\\Fileserver\SomeDirectory'

New-Item "FileSystem::$DirectoryLocation" -ItemType directory

$ACLNeedingModification = Get-ACL "FileSystem::$DirectoryLocation"

$NewACLRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('Domain\Testy Testerson', 'Modify', 'Allow')

$ACLNeedingModification.SetAccessRule($NewACLRule) #Error occurs here

Set-ACL "FileSystem::$DirectoryLocation" $ACLNeedingModification
```

Now, my guess would be I could do a somewhat hodgepodge solution by using the SID of the user instead and just jamming that in and waiting for propagation to complete the link. That being said, I'd vastly prefer to find a way that would allow me to tell the SetAccessRule method to look at a specific DC, similar to the AD commands. The documentation for SetAccessRule was pretty sparse on how the resolution occurs, so I was wondering if anyone on here had a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thanks a bunch for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [PowerShell: Script failing because AD objects have not replicated soon enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859969/powershell-script-failing-becuase-ad-objects-have-not-replicated-soon-enough?rq=1). I'm having the same problem too and I'll try to figure it out over the next few days. If I find anything useful, I'll update this answer. This http://ss64.com/ps/set-addomainmode.html may be useful but I'm not sure yet.

Edit: I wrote a cmdlet that waits for an AD object to propagate to all the domain controllers.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Wait for an AD object to propagate to all domain controllers.

.DESCRIPTION
    This cmdlet enumerates the domain controllers in the current domain and
    polls each one in turn until the specified object exists on each one. If
    the object doesn't propagate completely inside the timeout time span, the
    cmdlet will throw a System.TimeoutException.

.PARAMETER LDAPFilter
    The LDAP filter used to locate the object.

.PARAMETER Timeout
    The time span this command should wait before timing out.

.NOTES
    Author: Alex Barbur <alex@barbur.net>
#>
function Wait-ADObject
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$LDAPFilter,
    [TimeSpan]$Timeout = '00:00:30'
    )

    # calculate when we should stop
    $stop = $(Get-Date) + $Timeout
    Write-Verbose "Will check until $stop"

    # iterate through the domain controllers
    $domain = Get-ADDomain
    foreach ($server in $domain.ReplicaDirectoryServers)
    {
        # wait for the object to replicate
        Write-Verbose "Checking $server"

        $object = $Null
        while($object -eq $Null)
        {
            # check if we've timed out
            $left = New-TimeSpan $(Get-Date) $stop
            if($left.TotalSeconds -lt 0)
            {
                # timeout
                throw [System.TimeoutException]"Object propagation has timed out."
            }

            # wait a bit and check again
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
            $object = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter -Server $server
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
New-ADUser -SamAccountName 'doe.1'
Wait-ADObject -LDAPFilter '(sAMAccountName=doe.1)'
```

Hopefully it's useful to someone.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We ended up speeding up replication a little so it's not a super pressing issue anymore. I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to manual SID naming to avoid this, but thems the breaks!